# $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, continuous, such that $xf(x)>0$ when $x\neq 0$. Show that $f(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I need to prove:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, continuous, such that $xf(x)>0$ when $x\neq 0$. Show that $f(0)=0$. Show that if we remove the continuity this result will fail. Give an example.

For an example, I thought of $f(x) = x$. This is functinuous, and $xf(x) = x^2>0$ when $x\neq 0$, but I can't make a non continuous version of this function to try. Maybe $f(x) = \frac{x^2-2x}{x-2}$? This functions is not continuous at $x=0$ but it's equal to $x$ everywhere except at $x=0$, so $xf(x)>0$ stills valid, but instead of having $f(0)\neq 0$ we don't even have a definition for $x=0$. Maybe if I define it with any number for $x=0$ it works?

Also, how to prove such result?

I tried considering:

$$g(x) = f(x)-x$$

Somehow if I assume $xf(x)>0$ I need to prove $g(0) = 0$, maybe using the intermediate value theorem. Any ideas? I can't see how $xf(x)>0$ helps.

Comment: "functinuous"?  For a discontinuous example, just take your $f(x)=x$ when $x\neq 0$ but define $f(0)=42$ (or any non-zero value you prefer).

Comment: Hint (for the proof part).  suppose $f(0)\neq 0$.  Then either $f(0)>0$ or $f(0)<0$ in a neighborhood of $0$.  Either way leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$xf(x) > 0$ implies that $f(x) > 0$ when $x$ is positive and $f(x) < 0$ when $x$ is negative.

By intermediate value theorem, we must have $f(c) = 0$ at some value between a negative and positive number, since we know it is non-zero everywhere else it must occur at zero.

Comment: +1 This contains the piece missing from Jacob Wakem's answer.

Answer (score 6):

HINT: Since $xf(x)>0$ whenever $x\ne 0$, you know that $f(x)>0$ when $x>0$, and $f(x)<0$ when $x<0$. (Why?) What does this say about $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$?

Comment: I know intuitively that since $f(0)$ is between a positive and negative number, and $f$ is continuous, then it cannot jump suddenly, it must go smooth. I don't know how this proves that $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}f(x)$, for example, is $0$. I know intuitively that is must be, but don't know how to prove.

Comment: @Guerlando: Prove that if $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ cannot be negative: if it exists (and it does here, since $f$ is continuous), it must be $\ge 0$. Then prove something similar for the limit from the left, and put the two together.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous, if $f(0)=a\gt0$, then there is an $\epsilon\gt0$ so that for $|x|\le\epsilon$
$$
f(x)\ge\frac a2
$$
Then for $-\epsilon\le x\lt0$,
$$
xf(x)\lt0
$$
which contradicts the hypothesis.

If $f(0)=a\lt0$, then there is an $\epsilon\gt0$ so that for $|x|\le\epsilon$
$$
f(x)\le\frac a2
$$
Then for $0\lt x\le\epsilon$,
$$
xf(x)\lt0
$$
which contradicts the hypothesis.

Thus, we are left with the conclusion that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: my proof is shorter and more captures the essence of the result. Please upvote me.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @JacobWakem: I won't downvote your answer, but it is not quite enough.

Comment: Nice approach which avoids intermediate value theorem here. +1

Answer (score 1):

f(x) is negative whenever x is negative and positive whenever x is positive. By intermediate value theorem f(0)=0.

Comment: Without more work, this does not show that $f(0)=0$. It only shows that $f(0)$ is between some positive number and some negative number.

Comment: @robjohn exactly. I don't knopw how to prove that $f(0) = 0$, just how to prove that $f(0)$ is between positive and negative

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: my answer shows that $f(0)\gt0$ and $f(0)\lt0$ both raise contradictions. The only value left is $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs  f(0) is between each sufficiently small postiive and each sufficiently small negative. Thus it is 0.

Comment: Your idea is good, but should be explained better. Since $f(1)>0$ and $f(-1)<0$, there is $c\in(-1,1)$ with $f(c)=0$. However $f(x)\ne0$ for $x\ne0$, so $c=0$. However, the statement can be weakened to the requirement that $f$ is only continuous at $0$.

Comment: @JacobWakem Explicitly, we know $f(x) > 0$ or $f(x) < 0$ on $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, so it must be equal to zero at $0$ itself.

Comment: @MichaelTong Actually your argument does not work. My argument that f(0) is between each small negative and each small positive and thus must be 0 does work. Your argument is that the function is nonzero everywhere else which doesn't prove that it is 0 at 0! You got it right in your answer though: just having trouble sleeping.